# Control's rearrangement on Stretch

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I have a usercontrol with some textboxes and textblocks inside it. I am trying to move the controls when the texboxes are stretching. Using:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="200"> 
      <.... />
</WrapPanel>
```

doesn't do the trick. Any ideas how to achive something like this? Do i have to create some custom layout that overwrites `Measure()` ?

Comment: If you don't describe how they are supposed to behave, then nobody can tell except you.

Comment: Did you implement the stretching of the textblocks and boxes? can you add the xaml code to the question?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck you are right, my question was very abstract. I have a textbox and a textblock in one row, a textbox and a textblock in the next row etc. If the textbox stretch and the textblock does not fit inside the row i would like to move the textblock to the next row.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger yes i use `HorizontalAlignment = Stretch`

Comment: Do you think a Grid with dynamic rowspan or columnspan would work?

Comment: @Απόσκατάς doubt that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Width="auto" MinWidth="100">a block</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Width="auto" MinWidth="100"/>
    <TextBlock Width="auto" MinWidth="100">next block</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Width="auto" MinWidth="100"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

you can remove the minwidth of the textblocks too.

Edit or this

```
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Width="auto" MinWidth="100">a block</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Width="auto" MinWidth="100"/>
    </WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Width="auto" MinWidth="100">next block</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Width="auto" MinWidth="100"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you @Florian Schmidinger. The problem should be that i didn't used `Width="Auto"` on my controls.